# Google Sheets: Copy in a cell the value of another cell with step of 4

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google Sheets with 20 values stored in 20 cell sepearated by 4 column spaces (Example: `A1=1`, `A5=2`, `A9=3` etc.) I want to copy these values in 20 consecutive cells (Example: `B1=A1`, `B2=A5`, `B3=A9` etc.).I Tried to use Google Sheet Autofill but it doesn't recognize the pattern. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Think IBM: It's Better Manually  :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
=OFFSET($A$1,(ROW()-1)*4,)
```

and drag

[image]

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=QUERY(A:A; "where A is not null")
```